# Generators in a $2$-generated $p$-group

Tags: frattini-subgroup

I suppose to have a 2-generated $p$-group $G$. I know that if $\langle a,b\rangle =G$, then $\langle aΦ(G), bΦ(G)\rangle = G/Φ(G)$, where $Φ(G)$ is the Frattini subgroup of $G$.

Is it also true that if I have $\langle cΦ(G),dΦ(G)\rangle = G/Φ(G)$, then $\langle c,d\rangle =G$ ?

Comment: Since $\Phi(G)$ is the set of all non-generators, $S$ generates $G$ if and only if $\langle S,\Phi(G)\rangle$ generates $G$; hence from $\langle c,d,\Phi(G)\rangle = G$ you can deduce that $\langle c,d\rangle=G$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is (not just for 2, but any number) the statement of Burnside’s basis theorem.

Comment: Indeed, thanks.